# Get the OAuth2/OIDC access token with every request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, access-token

I'm trying to enable multi-tenancy for a previously single-user system. The application used to run on a local server and had a relatively simple frontend baked in.

Now I want to allow multiple users to simultaneously use it in a cloud environment. I went ahead and implemented Auth2 with OIDC and PKCE to redirect users to an external Auth Provider. What I want now is that for every request, the user sends his Access token with the request in order for me to decide what data to provide with the answer.

I could not figure out how to obtain that data, as it seems that the spring framework (by default) only sends the ID token with the request. I suspect the fact that my software would simultaneously be the client and the resource server has something to do with it.

This is my first question, so I'm very happy to modify or extend my question if I've forgotten anything.

What I've tried to far:

I've used Postman to verify that the three tokens, ID token, refresh token and access token are issued correctly and can be retrieved with my credentials.

I tried getting the access token from the request itself. Any parameters (like `@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser`) in the controller that include the token, however, are only showing the ID token and not the access token.

Getting the token via the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` does not work either, same problem, as I can only get the ID token, but not the access token.

---

Update #1, 13.12.2022/11:40: I am using PingOne by PingIdentity as the authentication provider and the following dependencies are or might be related or helpful to this matter:

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-security
- spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
- spring-boot-starter-web-services
- spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server

Comment: maybe this tutorial will help: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui In there, I send OAuth2 authorized requests from a client (Tymeleaf @Controller) to a resource-server (@RestController) using `WebClient` configured to use identified user's access-token

Comment: "The aim here is to demo OAuth2 configuration when a Spring backend is both a client and a resource-server." - sound extremely promising. I'll try to follow this now and tell you how it went.

Comment: Unfortunately, the prerequisites didn't fit my needs. Thanks for sharing, though!

Comment: What prerequisite exactly?

Comment: The one that disallows my to redirect unauthorized users to a login-page.

Comment: Then you'll have important security issues

Comment: Could be more specific? What important issues? I'd be interested to understand what you know.

Comment: To start with, users credentials are authorization-server business and should be exposed to neither client nor resource server.  The more actors see it, the larger is the attack surface. Second, unless you do not use any client side scripting language, you take the responsibility that the versions of those languages (and the platforms it runs into) are not exposed to any breach. All that not mentioning that if you spread login a cross clients, security improvements will have to be applied to all clients (MFA, security patches,...).

Comment: To take a simple sample, I would not trust a third party client asking my Google password to query Google API because this is precisely what OAuth2 solves. It would mean that the authors intentionally want to access my password or have not understood OAuth2 (which isn't a good news for security and is enough to prevent me from giving them any secret)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to those who tried to help me, but eventually I figured it out myself.

I extended my Controllers by two attributes: `OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication` and `HttpServletRequest request`.

[image: Controller-methods signature]

Also, I `@Autowired` in the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`.

[image: Autowired client-repository]

This then allows the following call returning the value of the accessToken:
`(oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(myClientRegistrationId, authentication, request)).client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();`.

After that, it's just parsing the token and retrieving the values using `JWTParser.parse()` and provided methods from the `JWT`-result.

Personal note: Don't do the parsing and retrieving value parts in your controller to keep any more complex logic out of it.

I hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Access-token format and validation is resource-server business, not client. From client perspective, access-tokens should remain black boxes. Do not try to decode a JWT or try to introspect an access-token from a client.

Comment: But my client needs to display certain information/options based on values from within the access token in the frontend. Any way of doing that without parsing the token in the client or elaborate token-ping-pong?

Comment: Use ID token or user info endpoint on clients. You can have config with opaque access tokens and JWT ID tokens (or no ID token at all and a user-info endpoint)

Comment: My token explicitly has "frontend" in the audience tag. The configuration is known not to change. I could try to use the userinfo-enpoint, but why would I if I already have the required information? Any justified arguments are welcome!

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/

Answer (score 1):

Split your security in two with `http.securityMatcher` in the first picked `SecurityFilterChain` bean to restrict the endpoints it applies to (use `@Order` to control that), and configure WebClient to add access-token as Authorization header to its requests to resource-server (REST endpoints). This is demoed in [the tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) I already linked in my comment to your question. This tutorial matches exactly what you are asking, the fact that it uses Keycloak instead of PingOne as authorization server is a detail (solved by editing a property or two).

## Resource-server security filter-chain

As reminder, a resource-server is a REST API secured with OAuth2. All end-points of `@RestController` and `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody` should be secured with a `SecurityFilterChain` containing `http.oauth2ResourceServer()`. The easiest way to configure a resource-server with Spring is using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (or one of the very [thin wrappers I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) around it which enable to configure it from properties with 0 java conf)

By default with such filter-chains, Spring populates the security-context with a sub-class of `AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?>`. You can retrieve the access-token from it. At least 2 options to access this Authentication instance:

- `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`
- have Spring auto-magically inject `AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?> auth` as controller method parameter

You can also have the original authorization header injected as controller method parameter with `@RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorizationHeader`.

I expose various ways to configure resource-servers security filter-chain in [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

## Client security filter-chain

End-points of `@Controller` returning a template name and secured with OAuth2 are clients. The easiest way to configure a Spring client is with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `http.oauth2Login()`.

Note that in this configuration, the request between the browser and the Spring client is not OAuth2 (it is most frequently secured with a session cookie, not a `Bearer` access-token in `Authorization` header). Only requests sent by the Spring client (on the server) to resource-servers are secured with OAuth2.

With client security filter-chain, security-context is populated with `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` which, on purpose, exposes ID-token  and not access-token. As reminder, ID tokens are holding user identity data and are intended to be used by clients when access-tokens audience is resource-servers and is designed for access-control. Clients should consider access-tokens as black box and use it only to authorize their requests to resource-servers (set `Bearer` `Authorization` header).

You can get the access-token string from `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`: `authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue()`, which is itself retrieved from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` you can auto-wire in your controllers: `authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("your-client-id", auth.getName())` (`auth` being the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` instance retrieved from security-context via `SecurityContextHolder` or controller method parameter injection)

If you need to authorize a `WebClient` request from client to resource-server, you can do simpler than retrieve access token and position authorization header: do as in the [UiController](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/UiController.java) of [the tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) already linked in my comment to your question:

```java
final var authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("spring-addons-public", auth.getName());
final var response = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/api/greet")
                    .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
                    ...
```

With WebClient configured as follow:

```java
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        var oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                        authorizedClientService));
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("spring-addons-public");
        return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
```